# How can I combine three select queries, each excluding the results from the previous ones?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's suppose I have three different select statements, like this

```
SELECT 'Final', ID FROM Stage WHERE stageCompleted = 1;
SELECT 'Active', ID FROM Stage WHERE StartDate < NOW();
SELECT 'Inactive', ID FROM Stage;
```

What I would like is some way of combining these such that it displays one table that

- returns the string `'Final'` and the ID of the row for all of the rows matched by the first query
- returns the string `'Active'` and the ID of the row for all of the rows matched by the second query but not by the first
- and returns the string `'Inactive'` and the ID of all the remaining rows.

I looked into all sorts of joins, but they don't seem to really fit the problem I'm trying to solve. How can I combine three select queries in SQL, where each one excludes the results from the previous ones?

Comment: Think about the problem a different way. You are wanting to return every row in the Stage table, but each row will be in only one "status".  You could get the same result set by UNIONing three different result sets, and use anti-join patterns to limit the rows returned by each, but that isn't necessary (in your case), and such a query would not be nearly as efficient as a single scan through the Stage table.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a case statement

```
SELECT
   CASE WHEN stageCompleted = 1 THEN 'Final'
        WHEN StartDate < NOW() THEN 'Active'
        ELSE 'Inactive'
   END,
   ID
FROM Stage
```

Comment: +1 This is the cleanest, most efficient approach, a single shot through the entire table.  There are other approaches to returning the result set, but they aren't likely to perform nearly as well as this will. (To be a little more precise, it's really a CASE "expression" which is used within the SQL statement.)